# Sitecore jss 20.0.3 install error: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk

I am on the latest version of node (18.7.0), all I am doing is trying to install a test Sitecore jss app. But the first step itself is giving me this error. Is there any version compatibility I should be aware of here?
[image]

Here's the log extract

```
21 verbose title npm install @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
22 verbose argv "install" "--global" "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
25 timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
26 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\acean\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
27 verbose logfile C:\Users\acean\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-08T14_42_57_575Z-debug-0.log
28 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 10ms
29 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load Completed in 30ms
32 verbose stack C:\Users\acean\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.7.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmfund:1
32 verbose stack ../workspaces/libnpmfund
32 verbose stack ^
32 verbose stack
32 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
32 verbose stack     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
32 verbose stack     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1049:15)
32 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:27)
32 verbose stack     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
32 verbose stack     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
32 verbose stack     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
32 verbose stack     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
32 verbose stack     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
32 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\acean\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.7.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\reify-output.js:16:38)
32 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
33 verbose cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
34 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
35 verbose node v18.7.0
36 verbose npm  v8.15.0
37 error Unexpected token '.'
38 verbose exit 1
39 timing npm Completed in 159ms
40 verbose code 1
41 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
41 error     C:\Users\acean\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-08T14_42_57_575Z-debug-0.log
```

I went back to an older version of node (16.13.0) and Sitecore jss CLI (19.0.0), but here I am unable to create a new jss app using:

```
jss create test-app nextjs
```

I am seeing the error

```
'Server sent 404 Not Found while enumerating templates.':
```

[image]

Please help in resolving this!

Comment: We need error messages and so on, included as text. Always. Never images.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I've added the log file text & the error message I see in text alongside version details.

Comment: @DurgaBose Did you try this command before creating JSS? `npm i @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@<version>`

Comment: @SumitBhatia Yes I installed v19.0.0 of sitecore-jss-cli. Please see the 2nd screenshot above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same with this configuration that you are using.

[image]

Then I run the following command and see the output.

```
npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@19.0.0
```

[image]

Then I run the same command that you used and got the same error.

```
jss create test-app nextjs
```

[image]

Finally I solved it by running the following command. And it worked for me.

```
npx create-sitecore-jss nextjs
```

See the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you need to run `npx create-sitecore-jss nextjs`.

This is a new feature that was added to `Sitecore JSS 20.0.0:` https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/releases/tag/v20.0.0

> New Features & Improvements [create-sitecore-jss]
>
> - New package containing initializers / templates for JSS sample applications (#881), (#883), (#882), (#880), (#879), (#878), (#876)
> - This replaces previous `jss create` method to create new JSS applications
> - You can now create an application with guided prompts using initializer command of choice (`npx create-sitecore-jss`, `npm init`
>   `sitecore-jss`, `yarn create sitecore-jss`)

So that is why `jss create test-app nextjs` works when trying to use `Sitecore JSS 19.0.0`. It doesn't work anymore with `Sitecore JSS 20.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade from node LTS (16.17.0) to 16.13.2 to get rid of that particular error.

Also install @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli **globally** first (with version 20.0.3) or better yet specify the version to install within the app directory `npm i @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@<version>`.

If you create the app locally without this version, it would default to a lower version and mess up some file generation, such as the file **[[..path]].tsx**:

[image]

The npx command for 20+ should be:

```
npx create-sitecore-jss
```